# Find memory mapped file with x64dbg

Tags: memory, x86-64, x64dbg

I have 64 bit process I want to debug with x64dbg. There is memory mapped file, I found with help of Process Explorer. Properties windows says:

```
Type: Section
Description: A memory mapped file or paging-file...
Address: 0xFFFFF8A002D8A080
```

But when I look into x64dbg Memory Map tab, there is no such addresses. I see only range `0000000000010000-000007FFFFFE0000`. How I can find memory mapped file? I want to place memory breakpoint on it.

Comment: 0xFFFFF8A002D8A080 is probably the kernel address, not the user-mode address. I guess you can use x64dbg memory search command to find the file content mapped into your process user-mode address.

Comment: @Tal yes, process explorer shows kernel address. Good idea with searching memory, it should work.